DAC and ADC Clipping, Headroom before Clipping, Peak and RMS confusion
If I wanted to calculate the back off or headroom of a signal  before clipping in an ADC, should this be the difference between the ADC peak full scale and the RMS of my signal or should it be the difference between the RMS corresponding to the ADC full scale and my signal RMS?
I feel that the latter should be the correct procedure because it compares RMS with RMS, yet I see sometimes that it is the former being applied giving a head room of an additional 3 dB. Which procedure is the correct one, and why?
So for example in a 2 V peak to peak ADC and a 50 Ω system the RMS corresponding to full scale is 10 dBm, so if my signal RMS is 0 dBm, do I have a head room of 10 or 13 dB before clipping? Which one is the correct number?

For a pure sine/cosine wave your calculation relating 2 Vpp to 10 dBm into 50 Ohm load is correct. But what's the question? Are you planning something where you never want to see any clipping, ever? Are you only examining sinusoidal wave forms? Or can they be more complex, like music or Gaussian noise (where the concept of likelihood enters)?

Thank you for your answer. What I am trying to do is simulate the impact of an ADC clipping on a signal in terms of EVM, and I am not sure if I should consider clipping to occur according to the ADC peak level above RMS of the signal  or the ADC RMS corresponding to peak above the signal RMS

Why don't you just share your thoughts? Apparently  there is no one else who can help me on this subject,,, so why not?

Because I'm an idiot and wouldn't make things better. It's not my area.

You're certainly not an idiot, and we are not trying here to make things better or worse, we are just exchanging ideas...doesn't matter if these ideas lead to anything or not, may they will and may be they won't, so what?

The correct number is neither. Or rather, it can be anything you want, depending on application.
In some cases, you don't know the waveform, so you don't know the peak vs RMS value of the signal, but may make some assumptions and then the signal can either fit the assumptions or then it won't and the signal clips.
Whether or the clipped waveform is acceptable or not also depends on your application, also how you deal with it.
So if your ADC has 2Vpp input range, you can feed in a 2Vpp sine wave or 2Vpp square wave, but the sine wave and square wave of same peak amplitudes have completely different RMS values.
But in general, some signals, like analog video are well defined. At least in studio or in theory. You have a video signal with parameters defined so that all you can do is to accept a certain max analog peak to peak input that could come from a camera, but depending on what is being filmed, bright scenes must fit into that definition even if currently a dim scene is being filmed. In a studio environment, the levels only allow very little headroom before the signal clips, but then again, clipping may not be that bad, things brighter than 100% white/green/etc just get clipped to 100%.
Another example from video is PAL colour composite. The analog signal can have larger peak amplitude than the ADC peak input is defined to have, but because the waveform is sampled at a specific instantaneous phase, the samples are always within ADC range and never clip, and the peaks that clip are between two digital samples.
In audio, like recording with a mic, you generally have a pre-defined environment for the signals. For example people can talk or play music at different levels, and there are transients that must be allowed without clipping. A studio may define that whatever the RMS level is, the allowed transients of 8x or 10x times that are the assumed peak value that must be handled.
